# Crystal Reports: How do I change datetime format to date?

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

In one report under database fields in the Field Explorer the field type says "DATE"
When I try to build a new report, the same field is datetime.

Can someone tell me how to change this to date? The end goal is to use Date, from the field Batch.ClosingTime in the select expert.

[I've attached screen grabs from the two different reports, the one on the left is how I would like it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx92P.jpg)

Comment: You can just convert to date using function CDate(Lastupdared) and use in report

Comment: Thanks Siva, I'm trying to apply that in the formula editor now.